# Problema al seleccionar elementos dentro de otros elementos con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Tengo un checklist que se arma dinámicamente con `Jqurey` según una selección previa, por lo que 
por momentos puedo tener 3 checks o 6 según el perfil del usuario que voy a editar.
Intento hacer que los checks se llenen con la información a medida que los selecciono, 
ya que de lo contrario traen como máximo 50000 registros y tarda bastante en cargar la pantalla.
No entiendo por qué no me funciona la selección `JQuery`.
Quiero llegar al `span` con la clase `dynatree-checkbox` que está dentro del `li` que 
está dentro del `ul` con clase `dynatree-container` que está dentro del `div`
con id `jstree_autorizaciones` para asignarle el evento `click` y ejecute una
funcion "x".
Acá dejo el código renderizado para que lo puedan entender mejor.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body" style="height:260px;max-height:260px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;">
    <div id="jstree_autorizaciones">
        <ul class="dynatree-container">
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                    <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Auditor</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                    <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Control de Calidad</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Control de Calidad en Bases</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Inspector</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="dynatree-lastsib">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-lastsib dynatree-exp-cl dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Tráfico</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedo seleccionar el `div` pero luego ya no puedo hacer que seleccione el resto.
Con esto selecciono el `div`: `$('#jstree_autorizaciones)`, luego intento agregar el
`ul` haciendo `$('#jstree_autorizaciones > ul.dynatree-container')`
pero acá ya no funciona y no sé que hago mal, todavía no manejo mucho JQuery pero
por lo que entiendo debería funcionar de esta manera. Luego seguiría con la selección hasta 
llegar al `span` que contiene la clase `dynatree-checkbox`, sería algo como esto:

```
var check = $('#jstree_autorizaciones > ul.dynatree-container > li > span.dynatree-checkbox');
```

Comment: Estimado, cuando se trate de código evita colocar imágenes, lo mejor es colocar el código que generó tu aplicación, de esta forma se puede eventualmente copiar y hacer pruebas.

Comment: Disculpas, tenés razón, ahora añado el código.

Comment: en tu codigo no hay un solo check list,
ni tampoco javascript debes publicac tu avanze y de hay en adelante se te puede ayudar

Comment: Debajo del código dejé las selecciones en JQuery que hice, expliqué la que me está funcionando y la que no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda claro para que quieres seleccionar el `div` ni para que lo quieres utilizar, pero te planteo una forma para poder obtener lo que necesitas sin tener que añadir todo ese recorrido.

Lo primero es añadir el método click a todos los elementos que tengan la clase `dynatree-checkbox`. Para ello podemos usar lo siguiente:

```
$('.dynatree-checkbox').on('click', function(){ });
```

Con esto ya tenemos el método on click en todos los div de esa clase. Ahora para poder saber en cuál de ellos he pinchado, puedo usar `$(this)` de `JQuery`.

Por último te faltaría añadir la funcionalidad que le quieras dar al método al pinchar. Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo detecto el click y cómo obtener el nombre del link dependiendo de en que `div` haya pinchado:

```js
$('.dynatree-checkbox').on('click', function(){
  alert('click en checkbox');
  name = $(this).parent().children('.dynatree-title').html()
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body" style="height:260px;max-height:260px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;">
    <div id="jstree_autorizaciones">
        <ul class="dynatree-container">
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                    <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Auditor</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                    <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
                    <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Control de Calidad</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Control de Calidad en Bases</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Inspector</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="dynatree-lastsib">
                <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-folder dynatree-lastsib dynatree-exp-cl dynatree-ico-cf">
                <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
                <span class="dynatree-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
                <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="dynatree-title">Tráfico</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente! es lo que buscaba. Lo que sucede es que es un form de usuario que trae miles de registros por lo que tarda bastante en cargarse. Por este motivo quiero hacer que traigan la información sólo los checks que el usuario va seleccionando.

Comment: Me alegro de haber podido ayudar.